# JQuery select the parent based on child containing exact text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following problem I can seem to get working: I have a set of parent spans containing a different set of tags but of which only 1 other span with a text inside. I want to extract the parents whose inner spans have the exact text match!

```html
    <span class="parent" id="1">
     <p>..</p><p>..</p>
     <span>text</span>
     <a>..</a>
    </span>
    <span class="parent" id="2">
     <span>some text</span>
     <a>..</a>
    </span>
    ....
    <span class="parent" id="n">
     <p>..</p>
     <span>other</span>
    </span>
```

When I search for "text" I want only the span with id == "1"

My original attempt with contains returns 2 spans -> id == 1 and id == 2:

```
var current = "text";
var element = $('.parent:contains(' + current + ')');
```

I have also tried with filter, which in my humble opinion should work but does not :(

```
var element = $('.parent').filter(function () {
                    return ($(this).children().text()==current );
               });
```

or

```
var element = $('.parent').filter(function () {
                    return ($(this).children('span').text() == current )
               });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Firstly, a block element as a P shouldn't be a child of a SPAN. And your second filter should work if only one span is child of parent one. So then maybe your browser parser parses it differently due to invalid HTML markup

Comment: @A.Wolff is right. Correcting the semantics first is advisable.

Comment: I used the last solution you have and it worked for me.  Maybe the text your searching doesnt match because of hidden characters.

Comment: you guys were right, apparently at the end of my 'text' there was a problem :(  I've been working on this for hours :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
var current = "text";
var test = $('.parent').children().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === current;
});
```

It looks like one of you solution but I tried mine and it worked. You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/amwadqm3/.

Comment: thank you, re running using your snippet made me found the error.. it was in html not in the JS :(

Comment: Good, at least you found your mistake! :)

Comment: I think this is not working either: OP is asking for the parent span (the one with id==1). But this solution is finding its inner span: the jsfiddle is colouring just the "text" string, when it should be also colouring the remaining ".." strings which are also in the parent span. @AdrianD accepted the answer, so perhaps the question was not properly stated.  He said "I want to extract **the parents**", and I have a problem which is exactly the same, but this answer does not solve it

Comment: @abu: OP said "re running using your snippet made me found the error.. it was in html not in the JS". Indeed my solution was not the right one but perhaps you can try the last solution he tried in his post.

Comment: Maybe the OP was helped by your answer, but it was not solving his question (which was clearly stated, and identical to my problem). The solution I tried was the one [provided below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38101926/710788) by @bman , and it worked perfectly. Actually, it's just a matter of adding one more _.parent()_ at the end of your jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

If you are adamant about using the :contains() css selector then your code should look something like this:

```
var contents = "test";
var element = $('.parent :contains(' + current + ')').parent();
```

Note the space between `.parent` and `:contains()`. This looks in the children individually for the given text and returns the element in which it was found. Then you must use `.parent()` to retrieve its parent element.

**However,** this will fail if the text that is placed into `:contains()` has special characters. It will also give false positives where a childs text contains the given text but does not exactly match it.

Instead, we can use a slightly modified version of the filter you posted:

```
var current = "test";
var element = $(".parent").children().filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == current;
}).parent();
```

Again, note that this filters through the children of the parent and not the parent itself.

Comment: this was a great solution as well, works also! thank you

Comment: in my opinion, this is the solution: the last parent() is the part that needed in the jsfiddle posted above by @Powkachu , so it actually finds text inside the inner span, but returns the outer (parent) span, as the OP had requested.  Thanks a lot bman

Answer (score 1):

you can get parent element using :contains or filter function. If you are not able to get parent element using :contains or filter function you can use each loop:

```
var content = 'test';
var element = '';

$('.parent').each(function() {
    var inner_text = $(this).find('span').text();
    if(inner_text == content) {
        element = $(this);
    }
});
```